# How do I solve $\lim(1+1/x)^{x^2y/(x+y))}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I solve this limit: it looks like euler can be used here, any ideas?
The answer is 1.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite:
$$\left(  1 + \tfrac{1}{x} \right)^{\frac{x^2y}{x+y}} =\left(\underbrace{\left(  1 + \tfrac{1}{x} \right)^{x}}_{\to \; e}\right)^{\frac{xy}{x+y}}$$
And for the exponent:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty,0)}\frac{xy}{x+y}= \underbrace{\lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty,0)} y}_{\to \; 0} \;\;\underbrace{\lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty,0)}\frac{x}{x+y}}_{\to \; 1} = 0$$
So $e^0 = 1$ follows.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x=1/t$ and compute the limit of the logarithm:
$$
\lim_{(t,y)\to(0,0)}
\frac{y}{1+ty}\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}=0\cdot 1=0
$$
So your original limit is $e^0=1$.